# How can I send a signal from one Python script to trigger another?

Tags: python, selenium

I am currently running a python script that interacts with an API to fetch inventory prices and when certain conditions are met, I send a post request to place this item based on its unique identification number into a cart.

The issue I am having is that after the item is in the cart, I am no longer able to interact with the API to post a buy, instead I have to go through the checkout process.  This can easily be done with Selenium, but the inherent issue here is speed because I must launch a chrome window, navigate to the site, login, etc.

Instead, what I would like to do is have two separate python scripts with one running the fetch and adding items to a checkout carts and the other running selenium, already logged into a buying account.  Once an item is placed in the cart, the script will send a signal to the other (already running, awaiting a command) selenium bot.

This may be possible with node, but have not done anything like this before - if someone could point me in the right direction it would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess u can use the `multiprocessing` module in Python to run the two scripts in separate processes, and then use the `Queue` class from the `multiprocessing` module to communicate between the processes.

For instance, here `buy` is being invoked after receiving a signal from the first script:

Script to add items to the cart:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue

def main():
    # Fetch inventory prices and add items to the cart
    # When an item is added to the cart, put a message on the queue
    queue.put("ITEM_ADDED")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Create a queue to communicate with the other process
    queue = Queue()

    # Start the other process
    p = Process(target=buy, args=(queue,))
    p.start()

    # Run the main script
    main()
```

Another script to initiate the buy process.

```
def buy(queue):
    # Wait for messages from the other process
    while True:
        message = queue.get()

        if message == "ITEM_ADDED":
            # Use selenium to buy the item from the cart
            # ...
```